# How to parse query strings in Iris

Tags: go, go-iris

Based on the [Hi example](https://docs.iris-go.com/hi.html) for [Iris](http://iris-go.com/) I want to create an application that can parse a request like

`wget -qO- "http://localhost:8080/hi?name=John"`
and respond with `Hi John!`.

Here's my handler code:

```go
func hi(ctx *iris.Context) {
    name := ctx.ParamDecoded("name")
    ctx.Writef("Hi %s!", name)
}
```

This just answers `Hi !` - how can I make it answer `Hi John!`

Comment: please don't use Iris: https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/issues/148 and http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html

Comment: @YandryPozo Thank you, I wasn't aware of this. I will have a closer look at the links you posted!

Comment: @YandryPozo I read the links and indeed I am now convinced that iris is not a good solution for me and also probably not for other people. I have added a remark to my solution below so other people become aware of these issues. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important: There is controversy about whether to use Iris at all as the author apparently deleted the history multiple times, which makes it hard to use as a stable API. Please read [Why you should not use Iris for your Go](http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html) and form your own opinion**

Just use `ctx.FormValue(...)` instead of `ctx.ParamDecoded()`:

```
func hi(ctx *iris.Context) {
    name := ctx.FormValue("name")
    ctx.Writef("Hi %s!", name)
}
```

If there is no such form value (i.e. query parameter) present, this will just return an empty string.

If you want to test whether a form value is actually present, you can use `ctx.FormValues()` to obtain a map. This is a little bit more complex, however, because the map contains a list of string values for each key:

```go
func hi(ctx *iris.Context) {
    form := ctx.FormValues()
    names, ok := form["name"]
    name := ""
    if !ok { // No name parameter
        name = "<unknown>"
    } else { // At least one name
        name = names[0]
    }
    ctx.Writef("Hi %s!", name)
}
```

Comment: Note there's nothing wrong with not accepting pull requests. Rewriting pull requests to change the authorship and remain the "sole contributor" however is not acceptable (this is probably way OT for SO :/)

Comment: @JimB Thanks, I mis-expressed myself in the edit. I've removed that part of the sentence so it does not cause misunderstandings if someone finds this Q&A

Answer (score 0):

```
func hi(ctx *iris.Context) {
    name := ctx.URLParam("name")
    ctx.Writef("Hi %s!", name)
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.